# HttpRuntime Cache value automatically cleares in idle

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, httpruntime.cache

we are developing an mobile application and we have used **WCF service to fetch SQL Server** data through online.

We are trying to authenticate each WCF Service call(server) by passing headers from client (mobile application). For this we have generated a token and passed the same in headers of each client call.

We have stored the tokens in HttpRuntime.Cache. But after few minutes [in idle mode] the cache entry is cleared.

**Note:** If continuously server and client communicates, it works perfectly.

Below is our WCF service Cache code:

**HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, Token, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);**

if some other better solution available, kindly suggest how we can save the tokens alone in server and authenticate the same from client for each service call.

Comment: I think your issue is "AppDomain Recycles". Like you said it happens when there's a period of no use. Based on configuration, IIS/ASP.Net will shut down AppDomains which are 'unused/idle' (thereby killing the in memory cache).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Kindly suggest how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Change recycle times? use 'out of process' or 'persistent' cache instead of in-memory cache? etc.

Comment: Kindly advice on how to change recycle times or kindly provide links for using 'out of process,Persistent' cache.?

Comment: If you are using .Net4+ try using System.Runtime.Caching instead.